# Why in two's complement (-1 >> 1) == -1 and not 0?

Tags: c#

**Note I think some commenters misunderstand my question that I don't understand integer division and floating point division - More clarification: I expected `-1/2 == -1 >> 1 == 0`, but in fact `-1 >> 1 = -1`.**

I'm learning two's complement. I understand a special thing about bit shifting in two's complement's context is that right shifting needs to maintain the sign of the bit, such that right shifting a negative number should fill in 1 instead of 0. And left shifting should always fill 0. This is explained in the [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Sign_extension).

According to the article, the motivation behind this is to maintain the equivalency of bit shifting operation and the corresponding multiplication or division by 2. However, a special case I immediately noticed is `-1`. Under the above mentioned rule, `-1>>1` does not equal to `-1/2`.

My question is how should I understand this? And what precautions should I take when applying bit shifts in optimization of multiplication and division?

Here's a C# (should be equivalent in other languages) code illustrating what I meant:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (int x in new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3 })
        {
            int a = x >> 1;
            int b = x / 2;
            Console.WriteLine($"Number:{x}, x>>1: {a}, x/2: {b}");
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the output of:

```
Number:0, x>>1: 0, x/2: 0
Number:1, x>>1: 0, x/2: 0
Number:2, x>>1: 1, x/2: 1
Number:3, x>>1: 1, x/2: 1
Number:-1, x>>1: -1, x/2: 0
Number:-2, x>>1: -1, x/2: -1
Number:-3, x>>1: -2, x/2: -1
```

Comment: The values you're shifting are `integers`. An integer cannot assume the value of 0.5. It can only assume the value of a whole number. Right shifting an integer will divide it by two, rounding towards zero. Incidentally, you cannot shift a floating point value the same way you can shift an integer, as floating point values are stored in a more complicated manner than are integers.

Comment: try actually writing out, say, 16 as binary and then shift it on paper to the right and see what happens, then you will understand. Shift it too the left too.

Comment: Right shifting an integer will divide it by two, truncating toward *negative infinity*. The example of -1 >> 1 shows that, the result is -1, not 0.

Comment: To get 2's compliment you take the inverse of a number and add 1.  So 0x0001 (plus one) gives 0xFFFE (compliment) + 1 0xFFFF (2's compliment).  0xFFFF shifted to the right will give 0xFFFF (code will shift in a 1 into MSB).  -1/2 is a fraction and you can never get a fraction when adding or shifting integers.

Comment: @Bob, I don't think you read my question carefully enough. By division, I really mean integer division. I revised my question in hope that it's clearer now.

Comment: Regarding the recent edit: the result is NOT rounded. It is truncated. It's your expectations which are incorrect.

Comment: Note that repeated question edits just confuse everybody.  I'm tempted to roll back to your original 'Why in two's complement -1 >> 1 does not equal to -1/2?' :((

Comment: "should be equivalent in other languages" - It is **not** necessarily. C# and C are **very** different languages. As are C++, Java, Python, Brainfuck, etc.

Comment: @Olaf. It is equivalent in this context. You're catching the wrong detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You should not use shift operatings in your code, if you are trying to do division.* The optimizer is able to figure this out better than you can. Of course, if you really know what you are doing and you are using unsigned integers entirely and you are writing in assembly, go ahead. Until then, just use the normal math operators for doing normal math operations.

If you are asking why `-1 >> 1 == -1`, well that's easy. The value negative one looks like all ones in binary, or 0xFFFFFFFF in hex. Shift the bits to the right and shift-in in a new 1 to the empty hole on the left, and you are left with what you started !

Comment: Right shift in C is implementation defined for negative integers. The example is about C#, which is a different language and may have very different behaviour. Your last paragraph is plain wrong, btw. The text contradicts the code and none is necessarily true for C and (according to OPs question) for C#).

Comment: @Olaf - the last paragraph had a missing negative sign. fixed.

Comment: @Olaf What is wrong for C? It is true for gcc and it explains why the OP gets -1 as a result.

Comment: Please read the C standard. Just because **one** specific version of **one** specific** compiler for **one** architecture generates such code, it is not necessarily true for all (and it actually is not, even for gcc).

Comment: Thank you. I think it is essential to understand the direction of the rounding is different in bit shifts then in divisions.

Comment: @Olaf - I wrote a test code (which I had posted, but removed because it was in C and not C#) that shows that gcc (4.8) on my architecture (x86_64) generates -1 when given `-1>>1`. I understand your point that this might not be true on all compilers and architectures, but it is true for this specific instance, and I bet most people running C# are running on a x86 machine with the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The results are still consistent.  The effect that a right shift by 1 has is division by 2 *rounded down*.

In the case of an odd positive value, the "extra" 0.5 gets dropped.  In the case of an odd negative value, it goes the other way.

In the examples you give above, half of -1 is -0.5, rounded down to -1.  Similarly, half of -3 is -1.5, rounded down to -2.

Answer (score 0):

**Why does `-1 >> 1 == -1`?**

Whenever you shift, the machine must fill in a missing value.  We'll use four bits just to keep things simple.  When you shift left, the bit that must be replaced is the trailing bit:

```
0101 << 1  // equivalent of 5 * 2
101_  // This is filled in with a zero
1010  // 5 * 2 == 10
```

When you shift right, the *leading* bit must be replaced.  But since the leading bit determines sign in signed 2s complement, we don't want to lose that sign (shifting left, or int dividing by some power of 2, should never cause a negative number to become positive or vice versa).  So the replacement value is whatever the leading (sign) bit already was:

```
0111 >> 1  // equivalent of 7 intdiv 2
_011  // Signed, so this is filled in with a zero
0011  // 7 intdiv 2 == 3

1111 >> 1  // equivalent of -1 intdiv 2, kinda
_111  // Signed, so this is filled in with a 1
1111  // -1 intdiv 2 == -1
```

However, if this was unsigned representation, the leading bit would simply be filled in with a zero:

```
1111 >> 1  // equivalent of 15 intdiv 2
_111  // Unsigned, so this is filled in with a 0
0111  // 15 intdiv 2 == 7
```

Further reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Wiki article is wrong for `c`. This statement: `These rules preserve the common semantics that left shifts multiply the number by two and right shifts divide the number by two.` is not correct for `c` when looking at odd negative integers.

For integer division `c` uses `round towards zero` (or `truncation toward zero` as it is stated in the standard), i.e. if the real result is `1.5` the integer result will be `1`. If the real result is `-1.5` the integer result will be `-1`.

For `c` the standard doesn't specify what should happen to negative integers when doing a right shift - it is implementation-defined.

If your system uses two's complement right shift doesn't work the same way as division. In general shifting has nothing to do with rounding. However, if you want to look at a two's complement right shift as a division, you  got to notice that it rounds towards minus infinity. That is: if the real result is `1.5` the integer result will be `1`. If the real result is `-1.5` the integer result will be `-2`.

Conclusion: Rigth shift is *not* the same as division by 2 for odd negative integers.

Your direct question:

```
-1 >> 1 is ??
```

If you consider right shift as a division by 2, the real result would be `-0.5` but since it works like round towards minus infinity, the result will be rounded to `-1`

But as stated - right shift is *not* a division by 2. You have to look at the bit level.

At bit level it is simply because the bit pattern for `-1`doesn't change. 
In two's complement `-1` is an `all-ones` bit pattern, e.g.

```
int a = -1; // Pattern 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111
```

when you right shift a two complements integer being -1 you simply get the same bit pattern and therefore the same value. You shift out a `1`at LSB and shift in a `1` at MSB. So the binary pattern stays the same.

So what happens to `-3`:

```
int a = -3; // Pattern 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111101
a = a >> 1; // Pattern 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111110 = -2
```

Comment: Please clarify if that is for C or C#. For C, this is wrong.

Comment: @Olaf it doesn't add any value when you claim something is wrong and cite the general c standard. If that's how StackOverflow is supposed to work, there's no need for any Q&As but google and documentation should suffice. In the context of bit manipulations for signed integers I don't see how c# and C differ in behaviors. And that is not even the main point of this discussion. If you truly want to be helpful, I'd suggest elaborating your reasoning.

Comment: My test also showed `(-3>>1) == -2` on gcc.(4.8.3) as well as the Intel icc compiler (15.0.2).

Comment: @Olaf - Could you be more specific about what you think is wrong. For division in C see: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5

Comment: This is a C# question. For shifts in C there are enought Q&A already. Also the standard is very ckear in leaving right shift to the implementation. And that very well differs even for gcc. There are more than x86/64 and ARM targets!

Comment: @Olaf- This was not a pure C# question. It was tagged as both C and C#. The question also clearly indicates that the C# code is just an example. So you shouldn't have removed the C tag. Also this question specifically address two's complement implementation for which the RSH is well defined and as I described.

Answer (score -1):

Consider this case:

-1 = 0b11

-1 >> 1 => 0b11 >> 1 => 0b11 (Many 1s on the left) (= -1)

If you look back -3 >> 1 case (prepare your computer's calc in programmer's mode)
you should see 0b111101 >> 1 becomes 0b111110 (-2)